# Can Fermat's last theorem be proven false with complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

Fermat's famous last theorem (a^n + b^n ≠ c^n, for n > 2) so far holds true.....with real numbers. I was wondering if it could be false if one extended it to complex numbers, that is, (a+bi)^n + (c+di)^n = (e+fi)^n...
I have tried to weaken the problem by assuming that n is 3 and that (a+bi) = (c+di) (for the Pythagorean theorem, it is valid to have two sides of the same length, and if one can prove the theorem false for two of the same complex number, it is still a valid counterexample).
Knowing that, I expanded 2(a+bi)^3 = (e+fi)^3 out into a nightmarishly long cubic equation, but now I am stuck because I am not sure how to simplify or combine both sides or even how to go about it.
I did take a look at the complex plane, and tried cubing the simple complex number 2+i, which turns out to be 2+11i. Then I picked another complex number, cubed it, added the two numbers together and I got a number that does not have an integer cubed root. That was just trial and error, though, not a very mathematically sound method, just looking for any patterns. 
My hope is that if the theorem can be proven false for n=3, can it be for 4? 5? Any other value of n?

Comment: The general question appears to be open, though particular exponents (like $n=3,4$) have been resolved.  [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90972/fermats-last-theorem-for-gaussian-integers-excluding-mathbbz-or-i-mathb) is a relevant link.  Note I am assuming that you are requiring $a,b,c,\dots$ to be natural numbers.

Comment: Lulu, a b and c can be any real integer, positive or negative.

Comment: I'm sorry, I looked at the link and I did not find a satisfactory (for me) explanation for exactly what Gaussian integers would satisfy it, and for what exponents, only that it had been solved. Also, an explanation of why, or how to go about solving this, would also be helpful.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem was proved for $a$, $b$ and $c$ natural numbers. It is false for real numbers and complex numbers. Basically, within these sets, one can just take the inverse $n^{th}$ root. So let us say we want $a$,$b$ and $c$ with $a^{3}+b^{3}=c^{3}$ then given values of $a$ and $b$, to find the value of $c$, we just need to take the cube root of $a^{3}+b^{3}$ which will always exist in the reals and in the complex numbers (in fact there will usually (almost always) be multiple solutions in the set of complex numbers).

Comment: If you allow negative integers then you have trivial solutions, like $1^3+(-1)^3=0^3$.  I think the link was extremely clear that the general question was open.  The author of the problem claims to have resolved the cases $n=3,4$ and includes a link to those cases but I have not looked at that.

Comment: FLT does *not* hold true with real numbers, but with natural integers. It’s not clear what you had in mind with your question, since it seems likely that you were using mathematical terms in ways not generally accepted. To have people take your question seriously, I’m afraid you’ll have to use mathematical terms in a standard, generally accepted, way.

Comment: For what it's worth, Kummer/Hilbert proved that FLT holds in $\Bbb Z[\zeta_p]$ for regular primes $p$ (I believe Hilbert made some changes to Kummer's proof based on some assumptions made when the class number of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$ is greater than $1$? Perhaps a real number theorist can enlighten us?)

Comment: [here](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/i32/i32.pdf) is what the author cites as a proof in the case $n=3$.  It uses a fair bit of the machinery of elliptic curves, but seems fairly straight forward given all that.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg  You omitted the (critical) remark that the Kummer Hilbert result is only for exponent $p$.  See, e.g., [this](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/fltreg.pdf)

Comment: @lulu Of course, I'd edit but it's been over 5 mins!